# Select row by Class

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select only one row by Class and the the select rows must be the lowest price.

I have this :

[image]

Result must be :

[image]

Comment: Don't add only some external links. Include the important parts here + your attempt. And it's ok if you don't add useless lines (see the first one and the last one). A better "thank you" is to keep a clean website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to get the minimum price per class:

```
select Class, min(price) as minimum from myTable group by Class
```

and then in order to add to this the rest of the columns, you need to join it together:

```
select b.* from (
  select Class, min(price) as minimum from myTable group by Class
) as a inner join myTable as b on a.class = b.class and a.minimum = b.price
```

Comment: Thank you Nir Levy i will try this when i will understand your query (2 days i thinks ;) )